# Virtual host not linking to correct website

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, domain-name

I have the domain designer-school.com and I am using my httpd.conf file to connect to a folder on my server and display the site.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/backend
ServerName www.designer-school.com
<Directory /var/www/html/backend>
Allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

All that happens is it links to the root folder not the one I am asking for. I have DNS records for the site as well.

Answer (score 0):

Now I feel a little stupid.I restated the sever with this

```
apachectl -k graceful
```

Everything is working now.